# How to remove double of brackets in pandas?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, brackets

I have difficulty with dealing the regex.

This is the dataframe I'm working on.
It's the data from kaggle
(url = 'https://www.kaggle.com/c/pkdd-15-predict-taxi-service-trajectory-i')
What I want to do is seperate every [longitude , latitude] for each row and use each unit of it.

For example, for each row
long&lat =  [long0, lat0] , [, ], [ , ] , [ , ],,,,,,           [long n,lat n ]
or 
long&lat =
and I want to extract each unit like 
long&lat[0] = [long0, lat0]
or
long&lat[0] = long0, lat0 if possible
How can I deal with it?

I tried some other methods like these.

```
df_concat['POLYLINE'][0].str.split(',')[0]
df_concat['POLYLINE'][:3].apply(pd.Series)
```

But couldn't find how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this dummy df

```
    long&lat
0   [100, 50]
1   [200, 150]
```

You can get lat and long values using

```
df['long'] = df['long&lat'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['lat'] = df['long&lat'].apply(lambda x: x[1])
```

Or simply

```
df[['long', 'lat']]=df['long&lat'].apply(pd.Series)
```

You get

```
    long&lat    long    lat
0   [100, 50]   100     50
1   [200, 150]  200     150
```